# is it possible to make target shared library file name variable according to environment variable in cmake?

Tags: cmake, compilation

I'm not familar with cmake but in CMakeLists.txt we  set the target shared library name like this.

```
add_library( mylib SHARED ${source_list} )
```

This generates libmylib.so and other settings in CMakeLists.txt are defined for mylib like
about the mylib
and also we can use shell environment variable to do some selective settings like

```
target_compile_definitions( mylib PRIVATE -DQQQ -D... )
```

Also it is possible to use shell environment variable to do some selective things.

```
if(defined env{MYVAR})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-g -DXYZ")
else()
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-DXYZ")
endif()
```

I would be happy if I could set the target shared library name as a variable according to the environment variable and use that selected name variable as the shared library name in all other settings.  In other words, is it possible to do things like below?

```
if (defined ENV{FOR_QEMU})
set_name(target_name "simlib_qemu")
else ()
set_name(target_name "simlib")
endif ()
add_library(target_name SHARED ${source_list} )
target_compile_definitions( target_name PRIVATE -DQQQ -D... )
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the output name of a target to anything you like via:

```
set_target_properties(target_name PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "whatever")
```

Then instead of `libtarget_name.so`, you'll get `libwhatever.so`. You would continue to refer to the target as `target_name` in your CMakeLists.txt.

---

**However,** since this will only work during configure time anyway, I strongly urge you to use a normal CMake variable instead. You may initialize it from the environment if it is not set, like so:

```
option(FOR_QEMU "Enable if building with Qemu support" "$ENV{FOR_QEMU}")

add_library(simlib SHARED ${source_list})
target_compile_definitions(simlib PRIVATE -DQQQ -D...)

if (FOR_QEMU)
  set_target_properties(target_name PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "simlib_qemu")
endif ()
```

This way, the CMake variable `FOR_QEMU` is the de-facto control and it is initialized on the first execution if the matching env-var is set. It will also appear *with documentation* in the cache, so other developers may query the build system directly for all its configuration points. Bear in mind: ***CMake is not Make*** and reading from the environment on every configure is a surprising behavior and generally bad practice.

Comment: Thanks, it works good and that was convenient! (but now I'm thinking of making two versions at the same time because they'll be exclusively used with different names now..)